# Sending information from one method into another method in a Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, user-input

I have my code finished for the most part, but I'm stumped on figuring out this last bit so that it will be finished.

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to make an applet that takes two floating numbers from the user via JOptionPanes, and gives the sum of those two numbers and the absolute value of the sum inside of a rectangle.

Like I said, I have the code finished, I'm just hung up on one part. I can't figure out how to  get the user input into the panes because I have placed panes into the init method while the rectangle and the string for the output are in the paint method.

I tried having the panes and the rectangle both be in the paint method, but that caused the panes to prompt the user twice before giving output, and I don't want that. That's why I put the panes in the init method.

Is there any way to call the information from the init method and put it into the paint method?

Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code I have made for this applet:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.awt.*;

public class MathApplet extends JApplet
{
    public void init()
    {

        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.##");
        DecimalFormat fmt2 = new DecimalFormat ("0.###");

        String intro, givenum1, givenum2;
        float num1, num2, sum, absum;

        intro = "Enter two floating point numbers, and their sum and the absolute 
                    value of the sum will be calculated.";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, intro);

        givenum1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the 1st floating point 
                                                       number now." );

        num1 = Float.parseFloat(givenum1);

        givenum2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the second floating point 
                                                       number now.");

        num2 = Float.parseFloat(givenum2);

        sum = num1+num2;

        absum = Math.abs(sum);
   }

   public void paint (Graphics page)
   { 
        page.drawRect (60, 80, 300, 140);
        page.drawString("The absolute value of the numbers is.", 100, 100);
        page.drawString ("The sum of the numbers is.", 100, 120);



    }

}
```

Comment: Store these values in fields.

Comment: Why are you calling System.exit inside the paint method?

Comment: Ahh, sorry. That was left over bit when I tried to have the panes inside the paint method. Off to delete it now.